# How to use input to refrence a specific object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is my symptom class:

```
class Symptom:
    def __init__(self, name, cost, infectivity, lethality, pain):
        print(self)
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.infectivity = infectivity
        self.lethality = lethality
        self.pain = pain
        self.bought = False

coughing = Symptom("coughing", 5, 50, 10, 5)
weight_loss = Symptom("weight_loss", 10, 5, 50, 15)
```

I want to be able to use input to ask which symptom the player chooses(trying to make Plague Inc)

```
symptom = input("which symptom do you choose? ")#player must choose between coughing and weight loss

symptom.bought = True
```

Comment: Hello John, if any of the answers here helped you, please consider accepting it by pressing tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
while not symptom: 
       symptom = input("which symptom do you choose")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control user, but can prompt user again for wrong inputs. You can't also ask user to read real class objects, instead use a string to choose between them:

```
coughing = Symptom("coughing", 5, 50, 10, 5)
weight_loss = Symptom("weight_loss", 10, 5, 50, 15)

symptom = ''
while symptom != 'coughing' and symptom != 'weight loss':
    symptom = input("which symptom do you choose? ") # player must choose between coughing and weight loss

symptom = coughing if symptom == 'coughing' else weight_loss
symptom.bought = True
```